# How can I tidy up this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a table called `questions` that contains `userid` and `questionid` columns, so that a row in the table means that a user with that `userid` has answered a particular question. I want to write a query to return an unanswered question for each user in the table.

An example would be:

```
userid | questionid
-------------------
1      | 3
1      | 4
2      | 1
2      | 4
3      | 2
```

And I want to return

```
userid | questionid
-------------------
1      | 1
2      | 2
3      | 1
```

From the original table you can infer the questions available are 1, 2, 3 and 4. User 1 has only answered questions 3 and 4, so I want to recommend answering question 1, user 2 has answered question 1 so I want to recommend that they answer question 2, and so forth.

I have the following:

```
SELECT q1.userid, 
(SELECT MIN(q2.questionid)
   FROM questions q2
  WHERE questionid NOT IN 
          (SELECT q3.questionid 
             FROM questions q3 
            WHERE q3.userid = q1.userid))
FROM questions q1
```

but this strikes me as being quite messy/inefficient. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: What does an unanswered question look like? Is it a row with a userid, and no questionid? Or the other way around? Or something else?

Comment: There will be no rows for unanswered questions - the table contains answered questions only.

Comment: You say 'return an unanswered question for each user.'  Do you mean a question that user hasn't answered, or a question that no one has answered?

Comment: Sorry, I mean for each userid, return a question from the list of total available questions that the user with that userid hasn't yet answered. Let me edit my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return *all* unanswered questions by doing:

```
SELECT u.userid, uq.questionid
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     questions q LEFT JOIN
     userquestions uq
     ON uq.userid = u.userid and uq.questionid = q.questionid
WHERE uq.userid is null;
```

(Note:  I modified the table names so they make more sense.  A table called `questions` should not be a junction table.)

But, if you just want one for each user, I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select q.questionid
        from questions q left join
             userquestion uq
             on uq.questionid = q.questionid and
                uq.userid = u.userid
        where uq.userid is null
        order by rand()  -- strictly optional
        limit 1
       ) as random_unasked_question
from users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as follows (SQL Server). The Common Table Expressions q and u should actually be tables (one table for questions only, one table for users only, leaving your original "questions" table to model the many-to-many relationship between them). The `unanswered` cte computes the set difference between the full cartesian product of questions-users and your actual table.

```
; with 
q as (select distinct questionid from questions)
, u as (select distinct userid from questions)
, unanswered as (
select u.userid, q.questionid 
from u, q
except
select questions.userid, questions.questionid
from questions
    )
select userid, min(questionid)
from unanswered
group by userid
```